# API waiting for a specific record on DynamoDb without pooling

Tags: events, amazon-dynamodb, synchronization, streaming, serverless

I am inheriting a workflow that has a reasonable amount of data stored in DynamoDb. The data is periodically refreshed by Lambdas calling third parties when needed. The lambdas are triggered by both SQS and DynamoDB streams and go through four or five steps before the data is updated.

I'm given the task to write an API that can forcibly update N items and return their status. The obvious way to do this without reinventing the wheel and honoring DRY is to trigger an event that spawns off a refresh for each item so that the lambdas can do their thing.

The trouble is that I'm not sure the best pub/sub approach to handle being notified that end state of each workflow is met. Do I read from an update/insert stream of dynamodb to see if the records are updated? Do I create some sort of pub/sub model like Reddis or SNS to listen for the end state of each lambda being triggered?

Since I'm writing a REST API, timeouts, if there are failures along the line, arefine. But at the same time I want to make sure I can handle the following.

- Be guaranteed that I can be notified that an update occurred for my targets after my call (in the case of multiple forced updates being called at once I only care about the first one to arrive).
- Not be bogged down by listening for updates for record updates that are not contextually relevant to the API call in question.
- Have an amortized time complexity of 1

In other words, in terms of cap theory i care about C & A but not P (because a 502 isn't that big a deal). But getting the timing wrong or missing a subscription is a problem.

I know I can just listen to a dynamodb event stream but I'm concerned that when things get noisy there will be more irrelevant stuff slowing me down. And I'm not sure if having every single record getting it's own topic is scalable (or how messy that would be).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamoDB streams in combination with Lambda Event Filtering so the Lambda function only executes for the relevant change you are interested in. More information is available here:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources/